# Creating Sitecore EXM Regular campaign programatically

Tags: exm

I am using Sitecore 9.1.1 and want to create an EXM regular campaign via code.

Comment: What is your intent with creating EXM regular campaigns programatically?

Comment: My  requirement is that if someone create one item based on particular template then i need create and trigger an EXM campaign mail as tghe newly created item will be set as message body